# How to do multivariable regression in Orange?

Tags: regression, orange

Orange contains a number of regression widgets, but they all seem to be univariable i.e. one independent variable that correlates to one dependent variable. When I have more independent variables that might influence a dependent variable, how to handle this in Orange?

Comment: Do you *want* to do this in Orange??? Seems to me that there's a lot better tools out there that will let you modify and maintain your data for the long term in a much better way.

Comment: Hi @I_Play_With_Data : Can you please mention names of some of such free tools . Orange comes free with anaconda and is really handy. But it would be great to use other tools which are powerful and opensource.

Comment: You got Orange by getting Anaconda. Anaconda is Python for data science. You have all sorts of Python functions for statistics in statsmodels, scipy.stats, and sklearn.

Answer (score 0):

The regression models are multivariable. You can go to the training videos of Orange to learn how to do regression.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do multivariable linear regression in Orange. The trick is feeding the linear regression widget with the right features (4 in this case, see picture) and target variable and then getting the regression formula/coefficients out using a data widget, see screenshot.

[image: (in thi]